# Tensorflow dataset, how to concatenate/repeat data within each batch?

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, tensorflow2.0, tensorflow-datasets

If I have the following dataset:
`dataset = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6])`

When I use a `batch_size=2`, I would get `[[1,2], [3,4], [5,6]]`.

However, I would like to get the following output:
`[[1,2,1,2], [3,4,3,4], [5,6,5,6]]`

Basically, I want to repeat the batch dimension by 2x and use this as a new batch. Obviously, this is a toy example. In a real case, if I have a batch of size `(64, 300)`, I would like to make a batch of `(128, 300)`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it by defining a map function

```
def double_input(x):
  x = tf.concat([x,x],axis=0)

  return x

dataset = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6])
dataset = dataset.batch(2)
dataset = dataset.map(double_input)

for x in dataset.take(-1):
  print(x)

>>>tf.Tensor([1 2 1 2], shape=(4,), dtype=int32)
>>>tf.Tensor([3 4 3 4], shape=(4,), dtype=int32)
>>>tf.Tensor([5 6 5 6], shape=(4,), dtype=int32)
```